# Java, failed test after changing Time zone on PC

Tags: java, spring, time, timezone, spring-data

Initially I had quite simple test:

```
@Test
public void testMe() {

    System.out.println("Records in H2 db:");
    List<DateRangeBean> all = dateRangeServiceImpl.findAll();
    all.forEach(x -> System.out.println(x.getDateTo()));

    Clock.system(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
    ZonedDateTime currentDate = ZonedDateTime.of(2016, 8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, clock.getZone());
    Date currentDate_date = Date.from(currentDate.toInstant());
    System.out.println("Current Date is: " + currentDate_date);

    List<DateRangeBean> result = new ArrayList<>();
    dateRangeServiceImpl.findGreaterDateTo(currentDate_date).iterator().forEachRemaining(result::add);
    result.forEach(x -> System.out.println(x.getDateTo()));

    assertEquals(result.size(), 2);
}
```

that always was executed on PC with default TimeZone UTC and with the following output:

> ```
> Records in H2 db:
> Mon Aug 08 00:00:00 UTC 2016
> Thu Oct 20 00:00:00 UTC 2016
> Thu Oct 20 00:00:00 UTC 2016
> Current Date is: Tue Aug 09 00:00:00 UTC 2016
> Thu Oct 20 00:00:00 UTC 2016
> Thu Oct 20 00:00:00 UTC 2016
> ```

where:
**dateRangeServiceImpl.findAll()** implemented as:

```
    public List<DateRangeBean> findAll (){
    List<DateRangeBean> result = new ArrayList<>();
    dateRangeRepository.findAll().iterator().forEachRemaining(result::add);

    return result;
}
```

**dateRangeServiceImpl.findGreatedDateTo(Date date)**:

```
    public List<DateRangeBean> test (Date currentDate){
    List<DateRangeBean> result = new ArrayList<>();
    dateRangeRepository.findGreatedDateTo(currentDate).iterator().forEachRemaining(result::add);

    return result;
}
```

and **dateRangeRepository** - is pure interface as part of Spring Data

```
public interface DateRangeRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<DateRangeBean, Long> {
@Query("from DateRangeBean drb where (drb.dateTo >= :currentDate)")
List<DateRangeBean> findGreatedDateTo(@Param("currentDate") Date currentDate);
}
```

and **DateRangeBean**:

```
@Entity
public class DateRangeBean implements java.io.Serializable {
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "date_To", length = 10)
    private Date dateTo;
.....................
public Date getDateTo() {
    return new Date(this.dateTo.getTime());
}

public void setDateTo(Date dateTo) {
    this.dateTo = new Date(dateTo.getTime());
}
```

}
Today I have tried to run this test on PC with Time Zone: **UTC -07:00** and test failed with the following output:

> ```
> Records in H2 db:
> Mon Aug 08 00:00:00 MST 2016
> Thu Oct 20 00:00:00 MST 2016
> Thu Oct 20 00:00:00 MST 2016
> Current Date is: Mon Aug 08 17:00:00 MST 2016
> Mon Aug 08 00:00:00 MST 2016
> Thu Oct 20 00:00:00 MST 2016
> Thu Oct 20 00:00:00 MST 2016
> java.lang.AssertionError: expected [2] but found [3]
> Expected :2
> Actual   :3
> ```

Okey, maybe, it is reasonable: we defined currentDate variable Aug 9 UTC TZ, but on the next step we re-converted currentDate to currentDate_date  in MST TZ and as result it is Aug 8.

BUT:

**Q1:**

based on our @Query: **drb.DateTo >= :currentDate**
in current case:  Mon Aug 08 00:00:00 MST 2016 >= Mon Aug 08 17:00:00 MST 2016 - this statement is incorrect!

Assume, that Spring Data compares only Day, Month, Year and trims Time segment.
Is it correct??

**Q2:**

I tried to fix the test putting the timezone directly in the test:

```
public void testMe() {
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
..............
}
```

But I still getting failed result:

> ```
> Records in H2 db:
> Mon Aug 08 07:00:00 UTC 2016
> Thu Oct 20 07:00:00 UTC 2016
> Thu Oct 20 07:00:00 UTC 2016
> Current Date is: Tue Aug 09 00:00:00 UTC 2016
> Mon Aug 08 07:00:00 UTC 2016
> Thu Oct 20 07:00:00 UTC 2016
> Thu Oct 20 07:00:00 UTC 2016
> java.lang.AssertionError: expected [2] but found [3]
> ```

And at the moment I can't understand how is it possible:

**Mon Aug 08 07:00:00 UTC 2016 >= Tue Aug 09 00:00:00 UTC 2016** ?

**Q3:**
I tried to specify TZ as part of Spring Context:

```
    <bean id="defaultZoneInfo" class="sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo" factory-method="getTimeZone">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="UTC"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="staticMethod" value="java.util.TimeZone.setDefault"/>
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <ref bean="defaultZoneInfo"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

but the result was the same as with **Q2**.

**Q4:**
Specify TZ in static block:

```
static {
   TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
}
```

and test - passed!

> ```
> Records in H2 db:
> Mon Aug 08 00:00:00 UTC 2016
> Thu Oct 20 00:00:00 UTC 2016
> Thu Oct 20 00:00:00 UTC 2016
> Current Date is: Tue Aug 09 00:00:00 UTC 2016
> Thu Oct 20 00:00:00 UTC 2016
> Thu Oct 20 00:00:00 UTC 2016
> ```

So, can someone explain why specifying default TZ in Spring Context xml file and directly in test method didn't fix problem?

And only specifying TZ via static block solved the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be your database problem not your application

for example Oracle database not accept connection from client after changing Client location in control panel.

Comment: maybe you are right, but I need to find proper solution for this problem. btw, for test I am using embeded h2 db.